# ADO.NET DataAdapters - Ensuring one Table is Update Before Another

Tags: c#, sql, ado.net, dataset

I am working on an application that inserts data into two separate, but related tables, when a user hits a submit button.

```
The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK_details_report"
```

However, because I have a foreign key restraint on one table, I have been encountering difficulties. I need the rows for one table (report_summary) to be inserted first, because of foreign key restraints, before even a single row is added to the other table (report_details). However, I would also like them to be handled in a single transaction, there might be some data integrity issues of one insert was to succeed and the other fail. How can I resolve this?

The T-SQL

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[report_summary] (
    [report_id]  INT  NOT NULL,
    [inspector]  INT  NOT NULL,
    [employee]   INT  NOT NULL,
    [room]       INT  NOT NULL,
    [date]       DATE NOT NULL,
    [score]      INT  NOT NULL,
    [locationID] INT  NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([report_id] ASC),
    CONSTRAINT [FK_report_summary_locations] FOREIGN KEY ([locationID]) REFERENCES [dbo].[locations] ([locID])
);



CREATE TABLE [dbo].[report_details] (
    [reportID] INT   NOT NULL,
    [itemID]   INT   NOT NULL,
    [points]   INT   NOT NULL,
    [comments] NTEXT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([itemID] ASC, [reportID] ASC),
    CONSTRAINT [FK_details_items] FOREIGN KEY ([itemID]) REFERENCES [dbo].[items] ([itemID]),
    CONSTRAINT [FK_details_report] FOREIGN KEY ([reportID]) REFERENCES [dbo].[report_summary] ([report_id])
);
```

and some of my C#

```
private void submitData(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    SqlTransaction tran = con.BeginTransaction();

    reportAdapter.InsertCommand.Transaction = tran;
    SqlCommand query = new SqlCommand("SELECT report_id FROM dbo.report_summary ORDER by report_id DESC", con);
    query.Transaction = tran;
    int nextReportID;
    if (query.ExecuteScalar() != null)
    {
        nextReportID = (int)query.ExecuteScalar() + 1;
    }
    else
    {
        nextReportID = 1;
    }

    detailsAdapter.InsertCommand.Transaction = tran;

    DataRow reportRow = ds.Tables["Reports"].NewRow();
    reportRow["report_id"] = nextReportID;
    DataRowView inspectorSelection = (DataRowView)inspectorBox.SelectedItem;
    reportRow["inspector"] = Int16.Parse(inspectorSelection["empID"].ToString());

    DataRowView empSelection = (DataRowView)employeeBox.SelectedItem;
    reportRow["employee"] = Int16.Parse(inspectorSelection["empID"].ToString());

    DataRowView locationSelection = (DataRowView)locationComboBox.SelectedItem;
    reportRow["locationID"] = Int16.Parse(locationSelection["locID"].ToString());
    reportRow["room"] = Int16.Parse(roomTextBox.Text);
    reportRow["date"] = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyy-MM-dd");
    reportRow["score"] = currentPoints;
    ds.Tables["Reports"].Rows.Add(reportRow);

    // update report_details dataset
    foreach (DataRow row in ds.Tables["Grid"].Rows)
    {
        DataRow reportDetailsRow = ds.Tables["Details"].NewRow();

        reportDetailsRow["reportID"] = nextReportID;
        reportDetailsRow["itemID"] = row["ID"];
        reportDetailsRow["points"] = row["Current"];
        reportDetailsRow["comments"] = row["Comments"];

        ds.Tables["Details"].Rows.Add(reportDetailsRow);

    }

    // update tables as single transaction
    try
    {

        reportAdapter.Update(ds, "Reports");
        detailsAdapter.Update(ds, "Details");
        tran.Commit();
        MessageBox.Show("Data Inserted");
    }
    catch (SqlException sqlEr)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(sqlEr.Message);
        tran.Rollback();
    }
}
```

I referenced this article by Microsoft (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/33y2221y(v=vs.110).aspx), but from my understanding, the Ordering section really applied when it was one table that required updates.

Thanks!

Comment: Do you have the relationships set up correctly for those two datatables in the dataset?

Answer (score 0):

First meet the requirements of the foreign key constaint with an insert. Retain that value and perform a second insert using the foreign key relationship.  Wrap these inserts in a transaction.

```sql
begin transaction
    INSERT INTO TableA (Id) VALUES (1)
    INSERT INTO TableB (Id, TableAID) VALUES (newid(), 1)
commit transaction
```

Comment: Thanks, I appreciate it, but not quite the answer I was looking. I am using ADO.NET data adapters - the question is how do I ensure the first adapter is finished updating (the first insert statement has been completed) before executing the insert on another table.

Comment: run the code synchronously - that is without delegates or callbacks.